# Ember protect multiple templates

Tags: ember.js

I'm fairly new to ember and are trying to create a app with a user login. I have solve this by using Auth0 and after entering credentials the user is redirected to protected.hbs. My question is how I make other templates inside of the login also protected. The protected route look like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin);
```

and the protected controller like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

I tried to generate for example protected/user-page but on the generated user-page I don't seem to be able access the session from the controller. Of course I could create a controller for every page but that don't seems like a good way of solving it. Is there a better more efficient way of protecting pages under protected? To make protected/user-page inherent the protected status from it's parent and also be able to access data from the session.

Sorry if it's a simple question but I'm really new to this and I haven't been able of find information about it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin);
```

You will have to do this on every route that you need to have user to be logged in. You only import session on controller if you need data from it like email but in most cases you only need it on application controller where you I presume have navbar with login info.

The other way is to use nested routes for example

```
 this.route('protected', { path: '/protected' }, function() {
    this.route('posts', {path: '/posts'});
  });
```

and then in protected.hbs

```
{{outlet}}
```

then you only need to do this on

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin);
```

on protected route

but I don`t see what is the big deal. Just follow basic procedures.

If you need something from controller you create controller you don`t have to overcomplicate things.